# Items showing up in export that aren't in the list

Tags: list, excel, export

When I export my list from SharePoint, there are extra items showing up in the excel sheet that are not in the list. Why is this?

Answer (score 0):

Excel can not invent the data for the extra rows. It has to come from your list. The most likely reason why you don't see these rows in SharePoint is that a filter is applied on your list.
It could be a different view, but in theory, if you start from a given view, the Excel export should apply to the same view.

Comment: I've checked recycle bin and all filters to make sure it wasn't hiding somewhere, still can't find it